# Creating a two dimensional binary matrix with constant sum along rows and columns

Tags: algorithm, matlab, networking, matrix, neural-network

I need to create a network model having 600 neurons. Each neuron can take 4 input connections. The Input to the neurons is from M(to be calculated) fibers, each fiber can give atmost 53 output connections to the neurons. Each of the connection that the neuron gets must be from different fibers (No two fibers should connect to the same neuron). It is mandatory that each neuron gets 4 inputs and it should be seen that there are no two neurons getting connections from the all 4 same fibers.The number of fibers used must be as low as possible.

P.S: I thought I could construct a 600xM binary matrix such that the sum of each row was 4 and sum of each column was maximum 53. How do you do it in Matlab or any other way. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

here a simple way to construct a binary matrix (600 by m) non zero rows will have a sum exactly 4, and each column will sum up to 53 (or lower if I understood you correctly) until there are more lines to fill such that their sum is 4:

```
m=12;
A=zeros(600,m);
cind=randperm(size(A,1));

for n=1:numel(cind)
        ind=find(sum(A)<53);
        try
            A(cind(n),ind(randperm(numel(ind),4)))=1;
        catch err
        end
end
```

Comment: Nice solution, one point you didn't check is: That it is mandatory, that different neurons must differ at lest in one input. At least i don't see where your code takes it into account.

Comment: It is also necessary that all 600 of the neurons are to be connected in the network. Here in case the sum exceeds 53, there wont be any 1's in that row. The randomness can allot the same positions to the 1's in the rows.

Comment: so should it be exactly summed to 53 or just 53 max ?

Comment: Hi @android_begginer94! By an chance were you able to find a solution? Can you please share it with us? Thanks in advance.